# Why does "Tiens bon" mean "Hold on"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

"Tien" means "yours" and "bon" means "good".So how does "Tiens bon" mean "Hold on"?

I am new French learner. I got to know about it from Google Translate.

Comment: Please don't rely on google translate, especially for everyday speech. It's ok sometimes for technical manuals.

Comment: tenir bon, an idiom means: to hold on, to stay the course, to hang in there, to not give up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misread the expression. The first word is not *tien* (your) but *tiens*, imperative form of the verb *tenir* (to hold).

- ***tiens*** (2nd person singulal)
- ***tenons*** (1st person plural)
- ***tenez*** (2nd person plural)

The latter gave the English "Tennis".

So

> *Tiens bon !*

is more like (literally):

> Hold "well" or Hold "good"!

Instead of Google translate, I'd recommend DeepL which translates ***Tiens bon !*** to :

> [**Hang in there!**](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/Tiens%20bon%20!)

Comment: Thank you so much( merci beacoup)